# Userscript @match & @exclude to match paths at certain level, but not sublevels

Tags: matching, firefox-addon-webextensions, userscripts, url-pattern, web-extension

How can one use `@match` and `@exclude` rules in a userscript to match URLs that have an arbitrary path at a certain level (a "level" being each new `/` in the path, not sure if there's a more technical name for it), but not at sublevels (i.e. having subsequent forward-slashes `/`)?

#### Example

A userscript is intended to match the homepage of any subreddit on Reddit.com, but not any sub-pages of that subreddit. This is what I've tried:

```
@match    https://*.reddit.com/r/*/
@exclude  https://*.reddit.com/r/*/*/
```

My understanding is that this SHOULD match, for example, `https://reddit.com/r/funny` but NOT match `https://reddit.com/r/funny/submit`, `https://reddit.com/r/funny/new`, `https://reddit.com/r/funny/comments/blahblahblah`, etc. However, my userscript seems to be firing on those sub-pages anyway.

I'm basing this construction off the [Mozilla documentation for Match Patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns), which states:

> ##### Pattern
>
> [https://mozilla.org/\*/b/\*/](https://mozilla.org/%5C*/b/%5C*/)
>
> Match HTTPS URLs hosted on "mozilla.org", whose path contains a component "b" somewhere in the middle. Will match URLs with query strings, if the string ends in a /.
>
> ###### Example matches
>
> https://mozilla.org/a/b/c/
>
> https://mozilla.org/d/b/f/
>
> https://mozilla.org/a/b/c/d/
>
> https://mozilla.org/a/b/c/d/#section1
>
> https://mozilla.org/a/b/c/d/?foo=/
>
> https://mozilla.org/a?foo=21314&bar=/b/&extra=c/
>
> ###### Example non-matches
>
> https://mozilla.org/b/*/
>
> (unmatched path)
>
> https://mozilla.org/a/b/
>
> (unmatched path)
>
> https://mozilla.org/a/b/c/d/?foo=bar
>
> (unmatched path due to URL query string)

I know I could solve this using the deprecated `@include` with RegEx (or RegEx in `@exclude`, for that matter, as Regex in userscript rules generally reduces performance). I know I could add logic to my userscript that validates the pathname before executing the rest of the script, but I'd like an elegant solution using only the basic `@match` and `@exclude` if possible.

Is there a better way to form these rules to make that happen?

Comment: The URLs you want to exclude don't have a **trailing** `/` so you need to remove it from `@exclude`.

Comment: Removing the trailing slash does not work because the asterisk wildcard can represent nothing/null, so `@exclude  https://reddit.com/r/*/*` would match (and therefore exclude) "https://reddit.com/r/funny/". To make matters more complicated, pages often have trailing slashes that aren't shown in the browser's urlbar for aesthetic reasons, so it's even harder to figure out whether a given url path will match.

Comment: The browser never hides the trailing slash in a *non-empty path* of a URL, it's the server's doing, so you'll have to use a regex or list all excluded pages explicitly e.g. you can add 26 exclusions for each alphabet letter + `*`.

Answer (score 0):

[Match Patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns) are working correctly, but there are other considerations.

### Test Script

Note: Some sites, like Reddit, use JavaScript to navigate between pages, which requires additional consideration to run the script.
Open each URL in a new tab, for testing.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Match Test Script
// @match         https://*.reddit.com/r/*/
// @exclude       https://*.reddit.com/r/*/*/
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('Match Test Script', location.href);
```

#### Result

Tested above with FM|GM|TM|VM and all were working as expected.

##### Match

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/
```

##### No Match

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/submit
https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/submit/
https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/14jmh7e/forging_a_return_to_productive_conversation_an/
```

---

### UserScript matching in manifest v3

Once MV3 [scripting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/scripting) is fully implemented for userscripts, all userscript managers are expected to use [Match Patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns).

### UserScript matching in manifest v2

Currently, userscript managers use different methods to match & inject userscripts.

- GM|TM|VM convert `match/include/exclude` to regular expression and manually check matching for injection
  *(TM has started to use the dedicated API in some cases on Firefox)*
- FireMonkey uses the dedicated API and Firefox checks matching for injection based on [Match Patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns)

Comment: (reading your answer) "Oh cool, they mentioned FireMonkey! So many people don't even know it exists." (reading your username) "Oh yep, that'll do it."

Comment: And so, the match rules do work accurately in the sense that they match on "reddit.com/r/funny/submit", but I don't want it to match that. I only want it to match "reddit.com/r/funny/" and no sublevels like "/submit". Is this possible using asterisk wildcards, or do I need to find every possible directory name for the subpages and @exclude those individually? (I know subreddits have "/submit" and "/about" but I'm not sure what else. Discovering them might just require clicking around randomly, and trial and error, so I'd certainly prefer if there's a wildcard-only solution)

Comment: @ETL I tested the above script in FireMonkey and it matches `reddit.com/r/funny/` and doesn't match `reddit.com/r/funny/submit`, as desired.